# Custom font not displaying correctly in TCPDF

Tags: fonts, moodle, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to create customised PDF certificates upon course completion on Moodle.

My fonts were originally OTF, which I have since converted to TTF to then get the .php, .z and .ctg.z files that TCPDF requires.

I've uploaded these to /lib/tcpdf/fonts and they are appearing in the drop down list of fonts.

However, when selected the PDF that is generated just uses a random generic font and not the custom font that I have uploaded:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak7F4.jpg)

Any ideas?

I have converted the fonts and been able to download the relevant files. I have uploaded them to the correct folders on the server and they appear in the drop down list of fonts to select, but when I go to use them for a PDF it just displays a generic font.